# Android Room Database Query without using Flow or LiveData (no observing)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to do a check in my apps Room DB. I want to check if a pin code has been used by querying the DB to find any results with that pin.

My DAO function:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE userPin = :pin LIMIT 1")
fun checkIfUserPinIsUsed(pin: String): UserTable?
```

I want to do this without having to observe that result because my query is executed when a button is clicked (validation is done).

How do I achieve this without getting the '`Cannot access database on the main thread`' error?

**EDIT: Example of how I want to check if the pin is used in the UI code:**

I need to use it in an if statement to check if the pin has been used and display a message on th UI. Like this:

```
if (checkIfExists) {
    show is used msg
} else { 
    fine 
}
```

how do I use an observer to get the result straight away?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, TableName.class, context.getResources().getString(R.string.db_name))
            .allowMainThreadQueries() // add this line
            .build();
```

Comment: .allowMainThreadQueries() is one way to do it, but it is not the best way, in some cases database operations on main thread can result in ANRs or poor user experience, it would be better to just to use a suspend function that is later executed in the view model

Comment: @JustSightseeing how can I achieve that without having to use an observer? I want it to check and return the result straight away.

Comment: normally you would just use an observer, a permanent one or a "get one value and stop" one, not sure why you don't want to use them (they will notify your UI without blocking the main thread and it will happen straight away)

Comment: @JustSightseeing I'm not sure how to implement it to be honest. I need to use it in an if statement to check if the pin has been used and display a message on th UI. If I have an if (checkIfExists) { show is used msg} else { fine }, how do I use an observer to get the result straight away?

I edited my question to have an example.

Comment: They aren't hard and are useful (over the years many observers were used: rx, liveData, SingleLiveEvent etc.), I guess your database query can be called more than once, is that correct?

Comment: @JustSightseeing yes, my query is in a viewmodel, and it's called everytime the validate button is called (save button validates input).

Comment: Then you don't have to add much work at all, just add a mutableLiveData at the top of your view model, post a value to it whenever your function finishes (and I mean a suspended function in a viewModelScope), then in your fragment / activity observe the mutable live data variable similarly to [this](https://sahasuthpala.medium.com/kotlin-simple-counting-app-with-view-model-live-data-fa3fdf074718)